# Docker Clustering multiple proxies fronting multiple tomcats

Tags: tomcat, docker, proxy, cluster-computing, kubernetes

ls,

I want to move a cluster of application servers fronted by proxies to a Kubernetes Docker environment. We now have a failover crossed clustering like cluster and we are using sticky sessions to limit resources needed for our memory prone solution (>2GB each Tomcat).

I am now struggling with the concept of each component as microservice. Both microservices (Proxy/Tomcat) should scale independently as needed. Also considering self healing of a service with a minimum of 2 containers. Each container should be agnostic eg: unaware of its surroundings, it provides a service to another component.

Now how would a proxy container binds itself to all underlying tomcat containers? How could a proxy container binds whit a tomcat container added/resurrected later than this proxy container started? Now how would a proxy container maintain stickyness to a specific tomcat container?

I purposely tried to keep question and description as minimal as possible, happy to give more details of course.

Regards, Corné

BTW sorry for the cross post i was in the assumption i posted to stack overflow in the first place
https://superuser.com/questions/1090867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution in this blog post

```
The solution is to directly load balance to the pods without load balancing the traffic to the service. This functionality is implemeted with service-loadbalancer in kubernetes. This implementation uses haproxy to enable session affinity and directly load balance the external traffic to the pods without going through services.
```

http://nishadikirielle.blogspot.nl/2016/03/load-balancing-kubernetes-services-and.html